# In chat, a oneboxed question/answer goofs out with a bad link when it's within a oneboxed message

Tags: bug, chat, hyperlinks, onebox

This is a little confusing to see and explain. Let's take [this chat message](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=4120276#4120276). Someone posted a link to an answer in the Tavern, and that link got oneboxed:

> [image]

This works fine. There's nothing amiss here.

Then that chat message was, in turn, [linked to in another chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/13848?m=25052077#25052077), and it got oneboxed, and so we also saw that original oneboxed link to the answer. At this point though, the link inside goofs out:

> [image]

A mysterious and undesirable "chat.meta.stackexchange.com//" has appeared. As you can imagine, [that URL doesn't work](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com//lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2107/how-can-i-quickly-cool-a-water-bottle/2109#21090), so it's not some clever forwarding scheme that's been implemented.

([Oneboxing by yet one more level](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25148915#25148915) does not appear to exacerbate the problem.)

Probably that undesirable portion of the URL should be thanked for its eagerness to help, and then disinvited from future links.